# How to compare two values using a contains function in a validation rule

Tags: validation-rule

I have two values:

1. Means of transport  API (Name)
2. Description (Description__c)

Whenever a new record is created:

1. Value should not be null.
2. Description contain means of transport value.

If I change the value it gives me an error.

I created the below validation rule:

```
OR( 
ISBLANK(Description__c ) , 

CONTAINS(Description__c , Name ) 
)
```

I am not sure how to compare the value of description and means of transport.

Answer (score 1):

Validation rules fire when the result is **true**. As such, if you want to make sure the field is not blank, and contains the value, then you need to use NOT for the second criteria:

```
OR( ISBLANK( Description__c ),
    NOT( CONTAINS( Description__c, Name ) )
)
```